# HtmlUnit - Submit and download PDF file

Tags: java, html, pdf, htmlunit

my problem is this:
when submit a form using the element `<input type="submit" name="method" value="Save">`, this open a dialoge open-save pdf file. 
Using HtmlUnit (ver.2.8) i can't download the file because the response returned the content of next html page and not the pdf file.

The configuration of my Web client is this:

```
private WebClient getWebClient() {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);

    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(4000);
    return webClient;
}
```

Then, the code used to submit the form is this:

```
List<HtmlElement> elements = (List<HtmlElement>) page.getByXPath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Save']");
HtmlElement buttonDownload = elements.get(0);
```

Finally, the method used to download pdf file is this:

```
public static void downloadByClickOnButton(HtmlElement buttonDownload) throws Exception {
    HtmlPage page = buttonDownload.click();
    WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = response.getContentAsStream();
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/to/save/file/test_file.pdf"));

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        System.out.println("Done!");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

The code works, but the file saved is the html text of page and not the pdf file.

What is wrong? Using htmlunit it is possible interact with open-save dialoge? Help me please!! :-)

This is the form:

```
<form name="ViewDocumentsFB" method="post" action="/Document/ViewDocument.do">
<input type="hidden" name="idRequestDocument" value="923390829">
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="metodo" value="Open"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="metodo" value="Save"></td>
</tr>
```

If i send this request manually:
http://----------/Document/ViewDocument.do
It is not opened a open-save dialoge and redirect to other page, why?

Thank advance.

Comment: I guess you mean version 2.18. Please post your complete case with URL.

Comment: I can't post the code with the URL because it is a istitutional website and access is allowed only with a username and password.

Comment: I tried to submit manually from the "view page source" browser and get redirected to another page ( file content which is then saved ) . If I do the same use case from the browser , when I click on " Save " opens the dialoge open-save PDF that can not save using HtmlUnit . It could be an ajax call ? There are similar instruments to HtmlUnit to navigate websites from java application?

Comment: There is `webClient.setAttachmentHandler()`, when the server returns `Content-Disposition=attachment`. Other than that, it is difficult to help when the case is not seen by others.

Comment: Thanks, I got my answer by your Question......